# Dataframe max matching two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe and I am looking for a way to find the maximum number on uniquly matched pairs on two columns.
If for example I limit my Dataframe to only these two columns:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | c |
| 4 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 5 | e |
| 5 | c |

The result shoud be:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | d |
| 5 | e |

So if I match **1** & **a**, then I cannot use **1** for column **X** anymore, nor **a** for **Y** anymore.

*The difficult part is to match the maximum number of pairs possible with this rule.*

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`linear_sum_assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) on the [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

tmp = pd.crosstab(df['X'], df['Y'])

idx, col = linear_sum_assignment(tmp, maximize=True)

out = pd.DataFrame({'X': tmp.index[idx], 'Y': tmp.columns[col]})
```

Output:

```
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  2  c
2  3  b
3  4  d
4  5  e
```

Intermediate crosstab (`tmp`):

```
Y  a  b  c  d  e
X               
1  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  0
3  1  1  0  0  0
4  0  0  1  1  1
5  0  0  1  0  1
```

###### other example

```
# df: here we removed the 3/b and 5/e pairs
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  2  d
4  3  a
5  4  c
6  4  d
7  4  e
8  5  c

# out
   X  Y
0  1  b
1  2  d
2  3  a
3  4  e
4  5  c
```